# Cross-platform settings / preferences implementation in Xamarin & Mono

Tags: mono, cross-platform, settings, preferences, xamarin

In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577760/settings-in-mvvmcross-core-assembly/16581042#16581042), some good solutions were suggested for implementing a cross platform solution for managinging user preferences / settings in a cross-platform manner.

While I can roll my own solution based on these suggestions, this seems like such a common need that I was surprised to find very little in the way of a ready-to-go cross-platform Settings / Preferences class.  If anyone knows of any, please do share!

Comment: See this - http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2291/cross-platform-preferencies

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late for the party, but I've written a library that solves exactly this problem:
https://github.com/flagbug/Lager